# How can I trace the value of an address in memory?

Tags: ios, debugging, assembly, arm, lldb

As the title suggests, I want to see from where came the value of a specific address. I am debugging an ios game with lldb. This game has a muliplier value of 0.4 (how fast combos decrease). I can change this value with cheat engine, but I want to know which instruction in assembly set this value to that address so I can change this instruction with hex editor. I used to use watchpoints breakpoints etc.. for variable values, but in this case, the value is constant and it is set when the app starts immediately.

Comment: If it's a constant then probably no instruction set it. It's just in the binary and is loaded into memory. Find which section it is in, then locate it in the file.

Comment: How can find which section is it in?

Comment: I assume cheat engine has tools for that. I have never used it so can't help you with that unfortunately. Same goes for lldb. Using gdb however, you could do `info symbol` which would give you the section then use `info files` to get the base address of that section. You can then subtract that from the symbol's address to get the offset. Finally, find the start of the section in the binary (e.g. using `objdump` or `readelf`) and add the offset you calculated in the previous step. You should then find your variable at that position in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent instructions in lldb for Jester's gdb steps are:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va <ADDRESS>
```

That will tell you everything lldb knows about that address.

Comment: Certainly looks simpler :D

Comment: When I enter "image lookup -va address-of-value" i got not output.

Comment: That means that address is not in any loaded sections from the list of images in your program.  That's usually because the address is in stack or heap allocated memory - from your description sounds more like the latter.